# Parameters in NamedQuery

Tags: oracle, jpa, netbeans

I am working with JSF 2.0, Primefaces 3.4, Oracle, NetBeans 7.2.1, and i got the following error:

```
ADVERTENCIA: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
Error Code: 936
Call: SELECT t1.OPT_ID, t1.OPT_ANT_FM_DET FROM SAE_PACIENTE t0, SAE_OPTOMETRIA t1 WHERE ((((t0.P_ID = ) AND (t0.P_IDENTIFICACION = ?)) AND (t0.P_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION = ?)) AND (t0.P_ID = t1.OPT_P_ID))
```

i have two beans SaeOptometria and SaePaciente; in SaeOPtometria i have this atribute that is the relationship with the SaePaciente bean:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "OPT_P_ID", referencedColumnName = "P_ID")
@ManyToOne
private SaePaciente optPId;
```

And also have the following namedquery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SaeOptometria.findByPaciente", query = "SELECT s FROM SaeOptometria s INNER JOIN s.optPId d WHERE d.pId=s.optPId AND d.pIdentificacion = :pIdentificacion AND d.pTipoIdentificacion = :pTIdentificacion"),
```

I am passing the parameters :pIdentificacion and :pTIdentificacion in the SaeOptometriaFacade file with the following code:

```
public List<SaeOptometria> consultaporIdYTI(String UIpIdentificacion, String UIpTipoIdentificacion){

    Query query= em.createNamedQuery("SaeOptometria.findByPaciente");
    query.setParameter("pIdentificacion", UIpIdentificacion);
    query.setParameter("pTIdentificacion", UIpTipoIdentificacion);
    List<SaeOptometria> SaeOptometriaList= query.getResultList();
    return SaeOptometriaList;
}
```

I clarified that the parameters pIdentificacion and pTipoIdentificacion in the NamedQuery belong to SaePaciente bean:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ1",sequenceName = "SAE_AINCR_PACIENTE",allocationSize=1)  
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="SEQ1")
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "P_ID")
private Integer pId;
@Size(max = 15)
@Column(name = "P_IDENTIFICACION")
private String pIdentificacion;
@Size(max = 20)
@Column(name = "P_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION")
private String pTipoIdentificacion;
```

why doesnt work?

thanks.

Comment: Remove "d.pId=s.optPId AND"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems wrong:

```
SELECT s FROM SaeOptometria s INNER JOIN s.optPId d WHERE d.pId=s.optPId AND d.pIdentificacion = :pIdentificacion AND d.pTipoIdentificacion = :pTIdentificacion
```

FROM SaeOptometria s INNER JOIN TO_WHAT

After your comment, I decided that my first understanding is wrong. 
You both join in FROM clause and in the from WHERE clause. Try to do only one of them.

Can you try following queries and report results:

First one: Join is provided by JPA. No explicitly providing Ids. This information should be given in your JPA mapping

```
SELECT s FROM SaeOptometria s INNER JOIN s.optPId d WHERE d.pIdentificacion = :pIdentificacion AND d.pTipoIdentificacion = :pTIdentificacion
```

Second one: you join explicitly. We give tables and join giving ID values explicitly.

```
SELECT s FROM SaeOptometria s WHERE s.optPId.pId=s.optPId and s.optPId.pIdentificacion = :pIdentificacion AND s.optPId.pTipoIdentificacion = :pTIdentificacion
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied this tutorial: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_select and the JPQL (of jsf 2.0) interpreted good the query, the problem is with the parameters.The query interpreted is this: SELECT t1.OPT_ID, t1.OPT_ANT_FM_DET FROM SAE_PACIENTE t0, SAE_OPTOMETRIA t1 WHERE ((((t0.P_ID = ) AND (t0.P_IDENTIFICACION = ?)) AND (t0.P_TIPO_IDENTIFICACION = ?)) AND (t0.P_ID = t1.OPT_P_ID))

Comment: I think Atilla is right, the problem is with the join, not with the parameters. The problematic part is the `(t0.P_ID = )`. Did you at least try his suggestions?

Comment: As Atilla mentioned, the query isn't valid.  S.optPid is an entity, so it doesn't make sense to compare it to d.pId, an Integer.  You don't need this at all because of the inner join defined in the from clause, but you would use 's.optPid = d' otherwise.

Comment: I tried with the first one, and it works perfectly. thank you for all.